# Windows PC freezes when waking from S3 standby

Tags: motherboard, freeze, sleep

I have a Windows 7 PC that I use as HTPC. About a month ago, the PC will freeze when it wake up from standby. The display will be blank and fan runs at full speed. The PC has Windows Update disabled, so it should not be caused by OS update. Also, the behavior when it froze suggests a hardware problem.

I tried resetting the BIOS and replacing the RAM and battery to no avail. I also tried unplugging power to optical drive.

I notice that if I change the standby, via BIOS, from S3 to S1. It will survive the wakeup. However, with S1 standby, the fan is always running which wastes electricity and shorten the lifetime of PC.

I am about to throw in the towel. Any ideas what I could troubleshoot? The motherboard is MSI G41TM-E43 (https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/G41TME43). Yes, it is old but it has been recording TV for me flawlessly.

What I have tried:

- Replace RAM
- Replace CPU
- Replace PSU
- Boot with Ubuntu Live USB (no freeze on wake, but cannot wake from USB keyboard/mouse)
- Reinstall Windows 7 (still freezes)

Comment: Boot using Live Linux CD/DVD/USB and try the commands 'systemctl suspend' or 'pm-suspend' (latter being part of pm-utils package) (in admin command prompt so prefix them with 'sudo')and put your PC into sleep and try to wake it up and see the results. If still issues you are likely to have a HW problem. If good then most likely something in Windows could be the culprit. Follow the below answer by Mr Ethernet to isolate the issue. Also check the health of the HDD/SSD that you have. Unplug any non essential USB devices if connected to your system.

Comment: continued...See if you can make out anything meaningful in the event viewer just in case. If nothing works, consider a clean install of Windows 7 as an option and check again.

Comment: I tried with Ubuntu Live USB multiple times but so far I have not reproduced the issue. However, I noticed that it also does not happen very often with Windows now. I don't know if it is related to the weather getting cooler.

Comment: I tried replacing the HDD and install Windows 7 again. Just when I thought the issue goes away, the freeze happened again after 2 days. I am just down to 2 options - replace the CPU or replace the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally have skipped the BIOS reset and RAM steps you already tried as they aren't a logical starting point. The BIOS reset is something I would not have done at all, as even if that worked you wouldn't know what setting was the problem as multiple settings would be changed simultaneously.

The most likely culprit is a single piece of hardware that isn't handling the change of sleep state. You want to focus on updating your drivers. Something may have updated recently that actually introduced this problem.

1) Update your BIOS then retest resuming from S3 sleep. This is not likely to solve it but will quickly rule out possible known issues with your motherboard that have been patched.

2) Manually update the driver for your video card, then retest.

3) Manually update the driver for your Ethernet and/or wireless card, then retest.

4) Manually update the drivers for all other hardware components, testing S3 sleep after each one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have finally found the root cause. The issue seems to be combination of TWO hardware. The PSU is of poor quality and it tends to cause power on issue with my aging motherboard. There is also a TV Tuner card (out of 2) that may be causing issue with freezing when my PC wakes up, possibly to record. After changing the PSU and yanking out the TV Tuner card. I have not experienced freezing for 2 months.